# How to use the Back Button on the NavController after the TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

How do I show the back button when the NavController is one of the ViewController of the TabBarController?

In the Storyboard view, it looks like this (this is how I want it):
[image: Storyboard screenshot of how it should be]

But when running in the simulator it shows like this:

[image: Screenshot of the result in the simulator]

Should I create the back button manually? I was avoiding having to do this to keep the back button's native animation effects

Comment: why do you have a navigationController before a tabBar Controller. you must remove it please

Comment: I placed this NavController because I thought the BackButton was not being displayed because I placed it as hidesBackButton = true, so I placed a new NavController as Present Modally so I don't have to hide the BackButton ... So, I must remove this NavControler and hide the BackButton using hidesBackButton = true when the user comes from the login screen?

Comment: when coming from login you should present TabBarController, if is ios13 using .fullScreen in modalPresentationStyle. so no back button in the tabbar

Comment: It's little confusing what you're trying to do having navcons both above and below your tabbar controller. If you have a navcon on every tab you can put a left button on each root view controller and dismiss your tabbar that way. If you want to have a navbar on the tabbar controller, take out the tab navcons and put left button on your remaining navbar.